# How to instantiate object with a block?

Tags: ruby

I want to achieve something like this:

```
object = SomeObj.new do
  instancevar = "value"
  anotherone  = "valuenew"
end

object.instancevar => "value"
```

But I have no idea how to design initialize method, I had something like this:

```
class Klass 
  def initialize(info = {})
    info[:property] = "value"
  end
end
```

I want to pass some hash in constructor to set instance variables, but also I would like to provide instantiating with block, but have no idea how to achieve this.

Answer (score 9):

Easy! You just yield the object to the block. See:

```
class SomeObj
  def initialize
    yield self if block_given?
  end

  attr_accessor :instancevar, :anotherone
end


object = SomeObj.new do |so|
  so.instancevar = "value"
  so.anotherone  = "valuenew"
end

object.instancevar # => "value"
```

Exact syntax from your question is impossible, because `instancevar` would be a local variable.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am exactly want to achieve!

Comment: This is what they call Ruby way.

Answer (score 7):

Ruby 1.9+: You can use `tap` method like this:

```
class SomeObj
  attr_accessor :instancevar, :anotherone
end

obj = SomeObj.new.tap do |o|
  o.instancevar = "value"
  o.anotherone  = "valuenew"
end
```

Now

```
obj.instancevar => "value"
```

Advantage: You need no special constructor

Comment: How `tap` is helping here? Could you explain please?

Comment: `x.tap` calls the block with the parameter `x`. `"a".tap {|s| s.size}` is equivalent to `"a".size`. The definition of `tap` is very simple: `def tap(a) ; yield a; a; end`

Comment: @Priti: Pragmatically speaking, #tap is syntactic sugar. You don't have to write `obj = SomeObj.new; obj.abuse; return obj`, you can write `return SomeObj.new.tap { |obj| obj.abuse }`, which looks neater to me. Theorists might say that my neatness intuition is there because #tap is Ruby's implementation of so-called k-combinator.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky thanks for the explanations. So is `#tap` for only neatness or any practical use-case. As `Brodski` says `"a".size` is same as `"a".tap {|s| s.size}`. So I will choose `"a".size`. But what is the advantage of `#tap`?

Comment: @Priti: Risking anger from functional programming fans, I dare to say that #tap is not adding any qualitatively new functionality to the language. Even those who are aware of it do not use it that often. So #tap is not really that interesting. Anything you do with #tap, you can easily rewrite without #tap. Concentrate on Ruby blocks and namespaces (modules), learn to use #instance_eval well, learn to make DSLs, that's what's important about Ruby.

Comment: You can [*"tap into" a method chain*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-tap) and you can perform some basic setup when creating objects without assigning it to a variable, e.g. `{"a"=>100, "b"=>200}.tap {|h| h.default = "Go Fish"}` Quite useful when writing tests.

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby 2.x, [which you can install here](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/), you can do this:

```
class SomeObj
  def initialize **named_parameters
    named_parameters.each_pair { |symbol, value|
      instance_variable_set "@#{symbol}", value
      singleton_class.class_eval { attr_accessor symbol }
    }
  end
end

o = SomeObj.new( foo: 42, bar: 43 )
o.foo #=> 42
o.bar #=> 43
```

Comment: You can use the same syntax (`foo: 42, bar: 43`) in Ruby 1.9 using ActiveRecord like constructors. (Accept hash as a parameter, then iterate over keys and set corresponding attributes)

Comment: @BorisBrodski: Yeah, I'm canvassing a bit too much for Ruby 2.0 installation, actually double asterisk `**` hash splash is the only novel syntactic element, which is not even needed in this particular usecase :-)))